# Get min and max value from database Linq to Sql query in MVC?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

here is my query that i have written in my controller

```
    public ActionResult Description()
    {
       var firstId = from p in obj.Cubisms
                      where p.Id = MIN(Id)
                      select p;
    }
```

but here "MIN" or "Max" gives error what should be the query if i am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx) functions to do the same,

```
  var min = obj.Cubisms.Min(r=> r.Id);
  var max = obj.Cubisms.Max(r=> r.Id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var firstId = (from p in obj.Cubisms select p.Id).Min();
```

Comment: Error :Parameterless aggregate operator 'Min' is not supported over projections.

Comment: @ab00764 why do you keep changing the accepted answer?

Comment: that was by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var firstId = (from p in obj.Cubisms
                orderby p.Id
                select p).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var firstId = (from p in obj.Cubisms select p.Id).Min();
```